# Check for allowed OpenVPN SSL/TLS cipher suites from the client-side

Tags: nmap, openvpn

I would like to check cipher suites that the OpenVPN server accepts. I used nmap:

```
nmap -sU --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 1194 <IP>
```

but the results are only:

```
Host is up (0.0033s latency).

PORT     STATE         SERVICE
1194/udp open|filtered openvpn
```

without cipher suites list. I also tried other tools like testssl.sh and sslyze but in these tools, I don't see in their documentation how to specify UDP port, and as result, I have only connection timeout.

What is the best way to check accepted cipher suites for OpenVPN?

Comment: OpenVPN doesn't use full TLS (which you use over TCP) nor DTLS, so you'd need an OpenVPN specific tool. It uses something inspired by TLS for key exchange but that's it.

Comment: OpenVPN actually uses TLS (optional but highty recommended) but in a weird way. It does not use OpenVPN-over-TLS-over-TCP but TLS-over-OpenVPN-over-TCP or TLS-over-OpenVPN-over-UDP. The standard nmap tool probably only support TLS-over-TCP.